# Eflite Receiver Hack

Tags: arduino, remote-control

I have the Eflite ELFH1025 receiver and remote I stripped from an RC Heli I had.  The thing is that it wants to control everything and to make sure every component of the heli is functional before it lets you control.

Thus it will flash green and red rendering it useless (or so I think).

I want to use it as an RC remote with an Arduino, is there any way I can get around this problem?

To clarify MY RC receiver wont read signals from the remote because it is trying to make sure the HELI is in tact, but I don't have to rest of the helicopter.  I just want to use the receiver and Remote.

Answer (score 1):

Without some specs for the receiver, this can't be answered in any detail. But the likely (not necessarily easy!) choices would be to 1) provide the signals the receiver is looking for from Heli; or 2) modify the receiver to skip the Heli check. You'll need more information to do either one.